# Displaying Multiple Rows with two tables

Tags: php, join, mysqli, html-table, rows

I'm not that good in programming PHP, and still learning from it.
Here's my problem, I need to display the result of rows from two different tables, had researched things and tried but all failed.

Hope someone could give some advice with my line of code.

```
$query = "SELECT tblparent.*, tblchild.* FROM tblparent, tblchild* FROM tblparent";
$num_results = $result->num_rows;
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );
if( $num_results ){
        echo "<center><table border='1' id='members'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<th>Parent ID</th>";
                        echo "<th>Parent Firstname</th>";
                        echo "<th>Parent Lastname</th>";
                        echo "<th>Parent Middlename</th>";
                        echo "<th>Child ID</th>";
                        echo "<th>Child Firstname</th>";
                        echo "<th>Child Middlename</th>";
                        echo "<th>Child Lastname</th>";
                        echo "<th>Action</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
                extract($row);
                echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>{$Parent_ID}</td>";
                        echo "<td>{$PFname}</td>";
                        echo "<td>{$PLname}</td>";
                        echo "<td>{$PMname}</td>";
                        echo "<td>{$Child_ID}</td>";
                        echo "<td>{$CFname}</td>";
                        echo "<td>{$CMname}</td>";
                        echo "<td>{$CLname}</td>";
                        echo "<td>";
                                echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_mem( {$Parent_ID} );'>Delete</a>";
                        echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
}
else{
        echo "No records found.";
}
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you're trying to get data from 2 DIFFERENT database tables, and put them into ONE HTML table?

Answer (score 1):

I see two mistakes:

1. you should satisfy the right order of statements, `$result` should be
   before `$num_results` assigment.
2. it seems that there is a mistake in your SQL query.

You need to adjust the following code, I am assuming that **tblparent** has an id and **tblchild** has a relation to **tblparent** id as **parent_id**:

```
$query = "SELECT tblparent.*, tblchild.* FROM tblparent, tblchild WHERE tblparent.id = tblchild.parent_id";
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );
$num_results = $result->num_rows;
```

Comment: btw, can I ask another question? 
Is it possible that if I delete the Parent_ID from tblParent, the record from tblChild from which it has a relation would be deleted too? Or i need to delete them both..

Comment: If it is the right answer, please upvote and/or accept it as solution. To your question search for [cascade](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/).